# Is there a new-style version of `UserDict` for Python2.6?

Tags: python, dictionary

Some classes in our code base inherited from `UserDict` to act like a `dict` object.

I was trying to apply a `metaclass` for them but I couldn't because they are old-style classes.

So, is there a new-style version of `UserDict` I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [inherit from dict](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html) in current versions of Python.

From the documentation:

> The need for this class has been largely supplanted by the ability to
>   subclass directly from dict (a feature that became available starting
>   with Python version 2.2).

Comment: The [Mapping and MutableMapping](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping) ABCs also provide a way to create objects with dict-like functionality, without subclassing `dict`.

Comment: There are heavy use of `self.data` in my classes, what is the equivalent of this when subclassing `dict`?

Comment: You can just index into `self` directly as if it were a `dict` instance. Because it is.